# How do you register multiple queues in Bull Board with NestJS

Tags: nestjs, bull, nestjsbull

Does anyone know how to register multiple queues with Bullboard Module and NestJS. Every documentation I have found show an example of how to register a single queue as seen below:

Bullboard Docs:
https://github.com/felixmosh/bull-board/tree/master/packages/nestjs

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    BullModule.registerQueue(
      {
        name: 'my_awesome_queue'
      }
    ),
    
    BullBoardModule.forFeature({
      name: 'my_awesome_queue',
      adapter: BullMQAdapter, //or use BullAdapter if you're using bull instead of bullMQ
    }),
  ],
})
export class FeatureModule {}
```

However what are you supposed to do when you have a module with multiple queues which seems like a common use case as seen below?

```
BullModule.registerQueue(
  {
    name: "download-youtube-queue",
  },
  {
    name: "upload-media-queue",
  },
  {
    name: "transcribe-queue",
  },
),
```

Seems like there should be a simple way to handle this.